# How to maintain stack in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stack, viewcontroller

I am building an iOS application. The issue I am facing is that How to present a particular view in app delegate and maintain the navigation stack ?

Right now what is happing is that on click on the push notification it takes me to initial ViewController.

What I need is on click of the push notification it should take me to that particular ViewController.

Suppose there are four ViewControllers: A,B,C,D . First thing I need is on click on push notification It should take me to D viewController and when I press back button of that View I can able to move to C View viceVersa B.

Please help me. I am new to iOS.

Answer (score 1):

In your AppDelegate, in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions


if( launchOptions )
{
    if([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey])
    {
        // Push your viewcontroller here
    }
}
```

If your app is lauch or in background, push your viewcontroller in:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

For your stack, something like that

```
ControllerB* B = [[ControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:"ControllerB" bundle:nil];
    [A presentViewController:B animated:NO completion:^{
        ControllerC* C = [[ControllerC alloc] initWithNibName:"ControllerC" bundle:nil];
        [B presentViewController:C animated:NO completion:^{

    }];
}];
```

Comment: I am using in same way my notification code is in the above condition but my question is how I can present a particular view in my application from appdelegate and maintaining the navigation stack example. navigation stack is - A,B,C and i present a see view and It should come back to B and then C. Please help me.

Comment: try to present them one by one with animated = NO

Comment: I am using your code here is my code - " Play * A = [[Play alloc] initWithNibName:@"Play" bundle:nil];
                HosteeEventDetails * B = [[HosteeEventDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"HosteeEventDetail" bundle:nil];
 [A presentViewController:B animated:NO completion:^{
 AcceptReject  * C = [[AcceptReject alloc] initWithNibName:@"AcceptReject" bundle:nil];
 [B presentViewController:C animated:YES completion:^{ }  "  I wanna to go c it is showing me error  - "'Could not load NIB in bundle: "

Comment: HosteeEventDetails, "s" is missing in the nibName.

Comment: I have correct the name now the problem I am facing is that - "Could not load NIB in bundle" Can you please help me in this

Comment: nope, in your code below, you have :  [[HosteeEventDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"HosteeEventDetail". The class name and nibName are not the same

Comment: I have make them same still facing same problem

Comment: can you please help me in understanding the Shinigami Answer given below.

Comment: The answer of Shinigami is a really good solution, but i think, you don't use a navigationController. For understand navigationcontroller, see this : http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/navigate-with-uinavigationcontroller-in-ios7

Answer (score 1):

@ejanowski is close to the correct answer, but OP is specifically talking about a "navigation stack", which implies `UINavigationController`. Calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:` will present the view controllers modally (and is just terrible anyway).

There is a handy method on `UINavigationController` called `setViewControllers:animated:`. You need to use that:

```
if (appOpenedByPushNotification) {
  UIViewController* A = ... ;
  UIViewController* B = ... ;
  UIViewController* C = ... ;
  UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:A]; // you might be able to just do [UINavigationController new] but I've never tried that.
  [nav setViewControllers:@[A, B, C] animated:NO];
  // show the nav however you want, maybe like this:
  self.window.rootViewController = nav;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer can you please tell me what will come in place of "... ;" as I am new in IOS.

Comment: "..." is your alloc/init method

Comment: Yeah, those are just creating and initializing the view controllers, either with `alloc/init` or from a `xib` file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to deep link from your notification to the ViewController you want to present. Without a deep link the app has no idea where to drop a user in the navigation stack. In your notification, include a value that indicates which view should present and handle the presentation in the delegate. Here's a bare bones example.

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

        NSDictionary *pushNotification = [options objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

        if(pushNotification )
        {
            //Check the notification to see which view you want to present and handle it here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using in same way my notification code is in the above condition but my question is how I can present a particular view in my application from appdelegate and maintaining the navigation stack example. navigation stack is - A,B,C and i present a see view and It should come back to B and then C. Please help me.

Comment: Yes. That is deep linking. It requires a decent amount of setup and you should read into it. You are going to have to customize your pushes based on the view you wish to present and then parse the push to figure out how you want to assemble the views.

Answer (score 0):

Yup should add the following code that is launched when the user click the notifications to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
if ([[launchOptions allKeys] containsObject:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {

    id userInfo=[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
      NSLog(@"%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]);
      //Open your view controller here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using in same way my notification code is in the above condition but my question is how I can present a particular view in my application from appdelegate and maintaining the navigation stack example. navigation stack is - A,B,C and i present a see view and It should come back to B and then C. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate.m add the following method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *viewControllerB = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerBIdentifier"];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewControllerB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the
 UINavigationController's `setViewControllers:animated:` method You will need to instantiate the relevant VCs, initialise them with any relevant data/state, and then build an array with them in order from the root view controller to the top view controller:

```
NSArray *newStack = @[rootVC, ..., page11VC, page12VC, page13VC];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:newStack animated:YES];
```

Then popping from page13VC will go to page12VC, etc, etc. You can get rootVC and any other pre-existing VCs using the `viewControllers` property of the navigation controller.

[iOS - How to push to a view controller and maintain the correct "View Stack" when going back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835841/ios-how-to-push-to-a-view-controller-and-maintain-the-correct-view-stack-whe?rq=1)

[How to pop back to specify viewController from navigationController(viewControllers/stack)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393308/how-to-pop-back-to-specify-viewcontroller-from-navigationcontrollerviewcontroll?rq=1)

Comment: This above code is valid for viewController only I want to use in appdelegate